# With another workbook sheet do this stuff this macro says to do

Tags: excel, with-statement

I have a workbook open, I'm trying to do stuff to another workbook, but calling a macro in the With statement just makes it act on the workbook I have open, not the other workbook that i want it to be doing stuff to.

```
Sub Format_Another_Worksheet()

    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = GetObject("C:\Users\john\Desktop\anotherworkbook.xls")

    With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Cells.Font.Size = 14

    Call myfunction("A")

    End With

End Sub

Sub myfunction(col As String)
    Range(col & "1").Font.Size = 30
End Sub
```

I have hundreds of myfunction macros I need to use and dont want to go in and start appending stuff to them all, In fact I cant touch these hundreds of other myfunction macros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then address the workbook by name.

I have a macro that works between two workbooks and I have this:

```
Dim wbmaster As Workbook                     'name for master workbook
Dim wbtarget As Workbook                      'name for student workbook

wbmaster.Sheets("Answers_Source").Range("h1:z160").Copy
wbtarget.Sheets("ANSWERS").Range("h1:z160").PasteSpecial
```

So it knows exactly what to do to which.

Answer (score 1):

Send the worksheet object on which you want to run this code as part of the function parameters:

```
Sub Format_Another_Worksheet()

    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = GetObject("C:\Users\john\Desktop\anotherworkbook.xls")

    With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Cells.Font.Size = 14

    Call myfunction("A", wb.Worksheets("Sheet1"))

    End With

End Sub

Sub myfunction(col As String, ws as Worksheet)
    ws.Range(col & "1").Font.Size = 30
End Sub
```

Obviously this has nothing to do with the `With`, but your `With` only has context inside the sub/function in which it's called. It doesn't live on through the function call.

Comment: but I have hundreds of long macros and I dont want to go into each of them and append this ws. all over the place

Comment: You have to go into them anyway as they currently aren't working, I assume. Perhaps a well created `find/replace` would help out here? In the end your `Range` object has to be qualified with the `worksheet` object to which it belongs. Otherwise it's helter skelter.

Comment: Ultimately your mistake was writing `Range.<whatever>` without putting `Someworksheet.` in front of it to qualify it properly. `Range` unqualified will work on `ActiveSheet` and lord only knows that is going to be in the middle of a huge spaghetti macro.